# How to re-add deleted build settings

Tags: xcode

XCode 7 has allowed me to delete a couple of project settings. How can I add them back?

Here's a picture of before and after...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projects settings aren't really gone completely, only your overrides of the default values were deleted.

So if you go to the `All` tab next to the `Basic` tab in your screenshots, you will see the `Base SDK` and `Build Active Architecture Only` entries. But you will have to set them again to the custom values you like.

Comment: I have values for those settings in a config file which were taking precedent over the values that I deleted. Why aren't they used when the values they override have been removed?

Comment: @IanWarburton What config file do you mean, Ian?

Comment: I added an .xcconfig file and overrode the deleted properties as described here... http://www.jontolof.com/cocoa/using-xcconfig-files-for-you-xcode-project/.

Comment: Aha... the file value was being used but it was stopping compilation. The config file only appears in properties for the target. I wonder why it lets you delete an item from basic properties?